# Oracle Linked Server in Azure SQL Database Managed Instance

Tags: sql-server-2012, linked-server, azure-sql-database

I am migrating my On Premise SQL Server to Azure SQL Database Managed Instance. But I have linked server to Oracle database in my SQL Server.

Can we create linked server to an On Premise Oracle Database in SQL Azure Database Managed Instance? Can anyone please guide?

If not, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Linked servers in Managed Instance support a limited number of targets. Supported targets: SQL Server and SQL Database Not supported targets: files, Analysis Services, and other RDBMS. For more information, please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-transact-sql-information) documentation.

You may consider to try with SQL Server installed on Azure VM using a private VNET instead of using a Managed Instance.